# Can you easily grow a RAIDZ with more disks?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-z

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start a ZFS RAIDZ zpool with two discs then add a third?](https://superuser.com/questions/281832/start-a-zfs-raidz-zpool-with-two-discs-then-add-a-third)
>   [RAID5 / RAIDZ - is it possible to enlarge without losing data?](https://superuser.com/questions/293699/raid5-raidz-is-it-possible-to-enlarge-without-losing-data)

I'm setting up a home Network Attached Storage using [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/). I was originally looking at a [RAID5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_5) solution, but then decided to look into [RAIDZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#RAID-Z).

Lets say I have 3 2TB disks in a RAIDZ configuration. How much space do I really have to use and how easy is it for me to add another 2TB drive to the array? Do I gain a full 2TB of free space?

Comment: Well.. what are you looking to mirror? 1 drive twice or 2 drives once? Be more clear in what you want to do and the answer will be how you can accomplish it.

Comment: actually, I think this question is a duplicate of this: [Start a ZFS RAIDZ zpool with two discs then add a third?](http://superuser.com/q/281832/494)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add extra drive in RAIDZ you'll have to recrete the array with extra disk. Which mean you have to back up all of your data. The capacity for RAIDZ is still N-1. For RAIDZ2 its N-2